# How do Mixins differ from Policy Oriented Design in C++

Tags: c++, mixins, c++-concepts

I've read various sources that attempt to explain Mixins in terms of C++.

They all seem to explain applications of Mixin which seem like nothing more than standard Policy Oriented Design.

[Link-1](http://www.thinkbottomup.com.au/site/blog/C%20%20_Mixins_-_Reuse_through_inheritance_is_good)  [Link-2](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/mixin-based-programming-in-c/184404445)

So my question:  Are Mixins synonymous with Policy Oriented Design or is there more to Mixins and their application in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are kinds of similar solutions.
Anyway, usually they are intended to solve slightly different problems.

Consider the following class:

```
template<PolicyDoX PX, PolicyDoY>
struct PolicyBased {
    void doSomething() {
        // ... A few operations
        PX::doX();
        // ... Some other operations
        PX::doY();
    }
};
```

Here is a trivial policy-based approach. The key concept is that the class expects the policies to have given (let me say) *interfaces*. It's a matter of implementations (how they are going to do that), not of what is actually offered.
In other terms, users of the class are not affected by the given policies in terms of functionalities, for `PolicyBased` offer the same interface in any case.

On the other side, consider this:

```
struct X { int i; void f() {} }
struct Y { char c; void g() {} };
struct Z { void h() {} };

template<typename... T>
struct Mixin: T... {}

using Full = Mixin<X, Y, Z>;
using Partial = Mixin<X, Z>;
```

In this case, the mixin *changes* its interface when you use a different set of components. The class itself doesn't expect any given set of functionalities and simply offer them to the end users.
Therefore, the mixin can be considered as a bucket where you can put almost every component to get your preferred type out and that type will have an interface strictly dependent on the chosen components.

To sum up:

- Policies define how to do something, but doesn't affect the interface of the class that accepts them.
- Mixins concur to create a new type with its own interface that is given by the set of components used to define the mixin.

Comment: I still don't see how in the 'Mixin' example you've given how it differs from Policy oriented design. X,Y and Z just seem to be polices of the composite called 'Mixin'

Comment: @JuliaSterbs The mixin class doesn't expect its specific types have any particular interface. The policy based design delegates to the policies specific functionalities, thus those types must offer fixed interfaces.

Comment: it's a bit difficult to see the difference - is that 'policy' requires a fixed interface  of doX, doY? vs, that 'Mixin' does not anything about X, Y, Z? Besides that Mixin 'unions' multiple types together, all it's added functionality is expressed through 'this' pointer in C++? (like the clonable CRTP minix example)?

Answer (score 2):

You linked to an article I wrote (the Think Bottom Up one), so I thought I'd chime in.

The similarity between Policy Based Design and Mixins in C++ is that the final class being defined will inherit from the classes that it is parameterised on.  Where they differ is that Mixins form a chain, and so they compose, whereas policies are somewhat stand-alone.  you could consider Mixins to be a case of applying a single policy and that policy has policies (note the recursion to form a chain of policies).

To me the power of Mixins are that MixinA can interact with Base, whereas if MixinA and Base were separate policies, they can't interact.  This will make the patterns appropriate for different situations.

Comment: this answer of distinction between mixin and policy seems not aligned well with @skypjack's answer? Wonders if anything was missed or misinterpreted?

Comment: @dragonxlwang I understand the question very well.  Policies of a class are distinct/decoupled and are siblings in the inheritance hierarchy while mixins have base/derived relationships and are highly coupled.